# How to do natural sort output of "uniq -c" in descending/acsending order? - unix

Tags: sorting, unix, count, uniq, natural-sort

**How to do natural sort on `uniq -c` output?**

When the counts are <10, the `uniq -c | sort` output looks fine:

```
alvas@ubi:~/testdir$ echo -e "aaa\nbbb\naa\ncd\nada\naaa\nbbb\naa\nccd\naa" > test.txt
alvas@ubi:~/testdir$ cat test.txt
aaa
bbb
aa
cd
ada
aaa
bbb
aa
ccd
aa
alvas@ubi:~/testdir$ cat test.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort
      1 ada
      1 ccd
      1 cd
      2 aaa
      2 bbb
      3 aa
```

but when the counts are > 10 and even in thousands/hundreds the sort messes up because it's sorting by string and not by natural integer sort:

```
alvas@ubi:~/testdir$ echo -e "aaa\nbbb\naa\nnaa\nnaa\naa\nnaa\nnaa\nnaa\nnaa\nnaa\nnaa\nnaa\nnaa\nnnaa\ncd\nada\naaa\nbbb\naa\nccd\naa" > test.txt
alvas@ubi:~/testdir$ cat test.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort
     10 naa
      1 ada
      1 ccd
      1 cd
      1 nnaa
      2 aaa
      2 bbb
      4 aa
```

**How to do natural sort output of "uniq -c" in descending/acsending order?**

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `-n` in your `sort` command, so that it sorts numerically. Also `-r` allows you to reverse the result:

```
$ sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 ada
      1 ccd
      1 cd
      1 nnaa
      2 aaa
      2 bbb
      4 aa
     10 naa

$ sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr
     10 naa
      4 aa
      2 bbb
      2 aaa
      1 nnaa
      1 cd
      1 ccd
      1 ada
```

From `man sort`:

> **-n, --numeric-sort**
>
> compare according to string numerical value
>
> **-r, --reverse**
>
> reverse the result of comparisons